# Google analytics tracking page zoom level with custom events

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I found this [script](https://github.com/yonran/detect-zoom/) that will track the page zoom. I've tested it with a `consol.log()` to confirm the results are accurate and that script is working. When I add that value in my google event tracking code I don't see it coming into google analytics. Is there something wrong with how i'm tracking my event?

```
// Track page zoom level
var zoomLevel = DetectZoom.zoom();

$(document).ready(function() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Site Info', 'Zoom Level', zoomLevel]);
});
```

Comment: `$(document).ready` is probably firing before GA is available. Could probably work if you add this _trackEvent array to the initial var _gaq[] array.

Comment: @Patrick Gunderson -- that shouldn't be an issue. When the async GA code does get loaded, it will process any commands pushed into the `_gaq` array. I'd consider moving the zoomLevel var into the .ready function though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The optional label parameter for `_trackEvent` is supposed to be a string, and can cause `_trackEvent` to fail silently if it's an int. Try

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Site Info', 'Zoom Level', zoomLevel.toString()]);
```

Also, I'd suggest using the optional nonenteraction parameter so the `_trackEvent` call doesn't affect your bounce rate:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Site Info', 'Zoom Level', zoomLevel.toString(), undefined, true]);
```